# Check if one column values is in the range of plus and minus 10% of another column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
        id  value1     value2
0  3918703    62.0  64.705882
1  3919144    60.0  60.000000
2  3919534    62.5  30.000000
3  3919559    55.0  55.000000
4  3920438    82.0  82.031250
5  3920463    71.0  71.428571
6  3920502    70.0  69.230769
7  3920535    80.0  40.000000
8  3920674    62.0  62.222222
9  3920856    80.0  79.987176
```

I want to check if `value2` is in the range of plus and minus 10% of `value1`, and return a new column `result_review`.

If it's not in the range as required, then indicate `No` as `result_review`'s values.

```
        id  value1     value2 results_review
0  3918703    62.0  64.705882            NaN
1  3919144    60.0  60.000000            NaN
2  3919534    62.5  30.000000             no
3  3919559    55.0  55.000000            NaN
4  3920438    82.0  82.031250            NaN
5  3920463    71.0  71.428571            NaN
6  3920502    70.0  69.230769            NaN
7  3920535    80.0  40.000000             no
8  3920674    62.0  62.222222            NaN
9  3920856    80.0  79.987176            NaN
```

How can I do that in Pandas? Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['value2'].between(df['value1'].mul(0.9), df['value1'].mul(1.1))
df.loc[~m, 'results_review'] = 'no'
print(df)
        id  value1     value2 results_review
0  3918703    62.0  64.705882            NaN
1  3919144    60.0  60.000000            NaN
2  3919534    62.5  30.000000             no
3  3919559    55.0  55.000000            NaN
4  3920438    82.0  82.031250            NaN
5  3920463    71.0  71.428571            NaN
6  3920502    70.0  69.230769            NaN
7  3920535    80.0  40.000000             no
8  3920674    62.0  62.222222            NaN
9  3920856    80.0  79.987176            NaN
```